# Accessing Web Information in Java During the Boot-up of Program

Tags: java, python-3.x

I am completely new to the Java language, and as my first project wrote a fifty line of so long code which would allow you to input a currency, an amount in said currency, and have the relative amount in other currencies (including Alliance Credits), and I ran into some trouble.  The code executed perfectly, and the only hitch was that the Bitcoin exchange rate, as well as others, fluctuated rapidly.  Is there some way I can have the program pull information off of the web every time it boots up in order to get the relevant exchange rates?
Preferably as a method that can be run in the main method. 
Also, If someone could adapt this to python that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes provided there is a importable package that has classes to browse internet and gives you information you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to access your favorite exchange url using `HttpURLConnection`, then get the html contents, parse it , and get the bit-coin exchange rate.
check this example, then you can look up the value inside contents variable based on the business logic, :

```
package com.jalalkiswani.stackoverflow.answers;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class UrlTest {
    public static String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            contents.append(line);
            contents.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println(contents);

    }
}
```

The below example will extract the bit-coin rate to USD from https://www.coinbase.com:

```
package a.b.c;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class UrlTest {
    public static String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.seprator");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        //URL of your service profile
        URL url = new URL("https://www.coinbase.com/charts");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //Connect to the website
        con.connect();
        //Open input stream to be able to read data
        InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
        //wrap inputstream in buffer for better performance
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        //start reading the webpage response line by line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            contents.append(line);
            contents.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        //print the webpage response for debugging, you may remove this line
        System.out.println(contents);

        //this is the element found just before the value in the page , i got it using inspect element in chrome
        String key = "1 BTC = $";
        //get the index of this above key that will return in the response
        int indexOf = contents.indexOf(key);
         //check if found
        if (indexOf != -1) {
            indexOf+=key.length();
            //get the exhange value based on this page response format
            String substring = contents.substring(indexOf, indexOf + 6);
            //print the exchange rate , of course you will need to parse it into double value
            System.out.println(substring);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }

    }

}
```

*Important* : you have to check whether it is legal to do that or not.

**EDIT**
Screenshot for the second example:
[image]

Comment: I tried the code listed and it did not print out the current exchange rate.

Comment: The second example will print the rate for you on the console. However , you shall use this technique with your favorite  exchange site. I have updated my answer to include screenshot .

Comment: I am a new coder.  Could you add comments to make it easier for me to understand the code?

Comment: Sure , i have just updated the second example with detailed comments.